# Execute Function when iFrame url Changes

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a signup form which is inside an `iframe` on my site and I want to create a redirect when the url of the `iframe` changes (when user successfully signed-up).

These 2 sites are cross domain and I know that it is almost impossible to pull the url cross domains but is there a workaround? I know the src will not change and  I was thinking to use `onload()`, when the `iframe` loads a second time (when user successfully signed-up), execute a function to redirect to a thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the javascript '**[Porthole](http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/)**'.

Its possible, but keep in mind the safety issues with iframes. The solution: if you have control of the original page + iframe, you can 'trick' the browser by implementing some javascripts on both sides.

First create a 'proxy' page on **both domains**. Name it 'proxy.html' or something (note: you have to use 'porthole.min.js', you can get this from the sources in the bottom)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <!-- Replace the url with your own location -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="porthole.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){ Porthole.WindowProxyDispatcher.start(); };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the **parent page:** (refer to the **iframe** proxy.html page)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="porthole.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="guestFrame" name="guestFrame" src="http://iframe.otherdomain.com/"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var iframeDomain = 'http://iframe.otherdomain.com';
var redirectUrl = 'http://www.mydomain.com/redirect-to/signed-up';

function onMessage(messageEvent) {
    if (messageEvent.origin == iframeDomain) {
        if (messageEvent.data["action"]
         && messageEvent.data["action"] == 'signed-up) {
            window.location.href = redirectUrl; // The final action!
            // This is the eventual redirect that will happen
            // once your visitor has signed-up within the iframe
        }
    }
}
var windowProxy;
window.onload=function(){ 
    // Create a proxy window to send to and receive messages from the iFrame
    windowProxy = new Porthole.WindowProxy(
        'http://iframe.otherdomain.com/proxy.html', 'guestFrame');

    // Register an event handler to receive messages;
    windowProxy.addEventListener(onMessage);
};
</script>
```

On the **iframe page** (refer to the **parent** proxy.html page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var windowProxy;
window.onload=function(){ 
    // Create a proxy window to send to and receive messages from the parent
    windowProxy = new Porthole.WindowProxy(
        'http://www.mydomain.com/proxy.html');

    // Register an event handler to receive messages;
    windowProxy.addEventListener(function(event) { 
        // handle event (not used here, the iframe does not need to listen)
    });
};
</script>
```

From the iframe you can send a message with javascript to the parent page (and also the other way). If you use only 1 javascript within the iframe domain, you can do something like this to send a message to the parent frame when the url is changed to something specific, for example 'signed-up.php' (untested, but you'll get the idea)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("signed-up.php") > -1) {
        windowProxy.post({'action': 'signed-up'}); // Send message to the parent frame
        // On the parent page, the function 'onMessage' is triggered.
    }
};
</script>
```

**Sources:**

- http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/
- Github: https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole
- Demo: http://sandbox.ternarylabs.com/porthole/